# can't get writing text in html text box in Webview of iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios

I have an external page which I call in webview in iOS app. the page has modal popup for the survey in which user need to input text. once the popup opens and tap the textbox, keyboard appears but the text is not updating in the textbox. Please give suggestion as I am new to iOS development. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is iOS7 bug,Try this

`<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, target-densityDpi=device-dpi">`

Setting `height=device-height` in meta tag seems to solve this.

Comment: @YadyneshDesai yes, It worked after applying reset CSS on textbox.
-webkit-appearance: none;