# iOS : input field does not display text when typed in but cursor still moves

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ipad, input

We use iPads in our warehouse and for some reason, some of them have issues with input fields. We have an HTML page which displays some text and has 1 input and a couple of buttons. When we focus on the input field, the keyboard shows up like normal, but when we type in, no text is displayed in the input field even though the cursor still moves as if it recognized that some characters were entered. The weirdest part is, if we zoom out, the text will actually appear.

When the above issue happens, if we submit the form with an "empty" input, it won't record the input's value, even though the cursor believes there were characters entered. If we zoom out and the text appears, then we can submit the form and the input's value is recorded correctly.

This does not happen on an Android device, it seems to be related to iOS only... any solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is hard to answer without seeing some screenshots and, crucially, the code for the section that isn't working properly.

Answer (score -1):

Check out this question, maybe the same solution would work in this case as well? [Input field bug on IOS - text turns white](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44795085/input-field-bug-on-ios-text-turns-white)
And this one - [can't get writing text in html text box in Webview of iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759432/cant-get-writing-text-in-html-text-box-in-webview-of-ios)

Comment: Duplicates should be flagged a such or presented in comments, not linked in answers.